# VirtualBox Ubuntu Guest VM freezes after Run /init process

Tags: server, virtualbox, freeze, 22.04

I am using 64-bit Windows 10 Host for VirtualBox 6.1.34 for Ubuntu Guest OS. As shown in the image below, my bootup freezes after this. Seems like some VirtualBox error (or) some Host machine problem. I tried changing different images, but my machine freezes exactly after this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tough one to tackle without a lot more info.  However, things to look at:

Some code will get stuck while waiting for an assumed ethernet connection.  Linux usually does a count down (30 seconds) if this happens, but I've seen it not do this at all.

Virtual Box probably isn't the problem, I'm betting it is your Linux config.  Try ctrl-c at the point of freezing.  Also, try booting into Linux boot menu and do a safe-boot.  You can also check logs at the time, too.